# Copy loaded object to another object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So from the title itself. I have an initialize object like say

```
"travellerDetails": { 
       "traveller_1": { 
              "Full Name": "", 
              "Gender": "", 
    }, "traveller_2": { 
             "Full Name": "", 
             "Gender": "",
    }, "traveller_3": { 
              "Full Name": "", 
              "Gender": ""
    } 
}
```

However, when I load my data object from an Ajax call

```
"travellerDetails": { 
           "traveller_1": { 
                  "Full Name": "John Doe", 
                  "Gender": "M", 
        }, "traveller_2": { 
                 "Full Name": "Jane Doe", 
                 "Gender": "F",
        }
    },
```

I get an error when I try to store the loaded data to an initialize object.

```
bookingForm.travellerDetails = data.travellerDetails;
```

I was expecting that traveller_3 will be set as "" considering that I only have 2 travellers when loaded. But when the initialize object is the same size as the one I loaded from an ajax call my code runs perfectly. So how do I copy the loaded object to the initialize one with different sizes?

Thanks!

Comment: `Object.assign(bookingForm.travellerDetails, data.travellerDetails)`

Comment: @adiga sorry bout that. it was a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the es6 [Object Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Try this:

`bookingForm.travellerDetails = { ...bookingForm.travellerDetails, ...data.travellerDetails}`;

This essentially means: make a new object with `bookingForm.travellerDetails`'s original properties, and override all the common properties between `bookingForm.travellerDetails` and `data.travellerDetails` with the data from the latter, plus add additional properties from `data.travellerDetails` if there are any. All the properties which are found in `bookingForm` but not in `data` will have the same values as in `bookingForm`.

Note that this is es6 only syntax, if you use babel you'll need [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread.html) plugin.